# How do I update Python variables in txt in real time?

Tags: python, http, flask

I have the code below who does the work, it writes to my txt file but it will take only the last http request.
The counter seems not to work, but when I use global variables it works.
I tried different methods, even with dictionary.
Can anyone point what I'm doing wrong?

```
@app.route('/request-counter', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'])
def write_to_request_counts_txt():
   file = open("request_counts.txt", "w")
   counter_GET = 0
   counter_POST = 0
   counter_DELETE = 0
   counter_PUT = 0
   if request.method == 'GET':
      counter_GET += 1
   if request.method == 'POST':
      counter_POST += 1
   if request.method == 'DELETE':
      counter_DELETE += 1
   if request.method == 'PUT':
      counter_PUT += 1
   file.write(f'GET: {counter_GET} POST: {counter_POST} DELETE: {counter_DELETE} PUT: 
   {counter_PUT}')
   file.close()
   return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: You're setting all the variables to 0 each time you call the function. You should get the values of the variables from the file and then increment them.

Comment: I suggest you use a format like JSON or pickle for the file, so you can parse it easily.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Barmar you should read the file.

Something like the code below:

```
@app.route('/request-counter', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'])
def write_to_request_counts_txt():
    with open("request_counts.txt", "r") as r:
       line = r.read()

    line_list = line.split(';')
    counter_GET = int(line_list[0].split(":")[1].strip(" "))
    counter_POST = int(line_list[1].split(":")[1].strip(" "))
    counter_DELETE = int(line_list[2].split(":")[1].strip(" "))
    counter_PUT = int(line_list[3].split(":")[1].strip(" "))
    if request.method == 'GET':
      counter_GET += 1
    if request.method == 'POST':
      counter_POST += 1
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
      counter_DELETE += 1
    if request.method == 'PUT':
      counter_PUT += 1

    with open("request_counts.txt", "w") as w:
        w.write(f'GET: {counter_GET} ;POST: {counter_POST} ;DELETE: {counter_DELETE} ;PUT: {counter_PUT}')

    return render_template('index.html')
```

I did not test the code.

I chose to use csv-like string approach. But you can achieve the same result using regex.
And you wouldn't need to change you file content format.

Comment: I adapted your code and it works. Tnx a lot! I also upvoted, but you won't be able to see it in a while :D

Comment: Yes, you must convert the string to numbers. But that's the idea.
You're welcome and good luck.